# ArrangoDB - Get All Possible Path From Given Value

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangodb-graph

I want a query to get all possible paths that start from a given vertex.

For exa. as in below image,
[image]

I want to find all paths that start from **"Covid/12109"** with Query.

So it returns like this

```json
    { "_from":"Covid/12109","_to":"Covid/12110" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12111" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12115" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12114" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12111","_to":"Covid/12115" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12111","_to":"Covid/12114" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12110" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12113" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12114" }
```

And if i want to start from **"Covid/12110"** then it should return like this

```json
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12111" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12115" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12114" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12111","_to":"Covid/12115" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12111","_to":"Covid/12114" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12110" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12113" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12114" }
```

And if i want to start from **"Covid/12112"** then it should return like this

```json
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12110" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12113" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12112","_to":"Covid/12114" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12111" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12115" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12110","_to":"Covid/12114" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12111","_to":"Covid/12115" }
    { "_from":"Covid/12111","_to":"Covid/12114" }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Graph traversal](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-traversals.html) is your friend here.  There are several ways to accomplish this, but you might start by :

```js
FOR c IN Covid
    FILTER c._key == '12109'
    FOR v,e IN 1..9 OUTBOUND c
        `has`
        OPTIONS { uniqueVertices: true }
        RETURN e
```

The name of your edge collection ('has') is tricky because [HAS](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#has) is an AQL keyword (see [the docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals-syntax.html#names) about naming things with keywords).  I've enclosed this in backticks (the AQL escape char), but you could also create a [named graph](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/graphs.html#named-graphs), which (I believe) is much more flexible.

Looking at the query:

- We first find documents in the "Covid" collection that match a key. This is optional, you could also swap the "c" in the graph traversal with a document id like "Covid/12109"
- `FOR v,e` represents "vertices" `v` and "edges" `e` to return
- `1..9` is the number of traversal "jumps" to perform. This can be any number (`2`) or range (`5..27`)
- `OUTBOUND` refers to the path direction to traverse. Other options here are `OUTBOUND` and `ANY`
- `{ uniqueVertices: true }` tells the engine to keep track of which vertices it's returned and not duplicate them on output.  See the docs [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-traversals.html#working-with-named-graphs)
- `RETURN e` will return *edge* ("has") documents. `RETURN v` would return *vertex* ("Covid") documents.